# Converting eps to png - dimensions

Tags: conversion, eps, ghostscript

When I convert EPS to PNG using this command

> gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r600 -sDEVICE=pnggray -sOutputFile=%1.png "%1.eps"

I get PNG picture with large dimensions, although the bounding box in EPS is correct.

For example from EPS with header

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0 EPSF-3.0
%%BoundingBox: 204 603 407 759
%%HiResBoundingBox: 204.242619 603.788607 406.691988 758.249977
%.................................
%%Creator: GPL Ghostscript 864 (epswrite)
%%CreationDate: 2011/12/10 21:30:18
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%EndComments
```

I've obtained a 4958x7018 png. This would correspond to the whole A4 page and not to the bounding box.

---

Here's the link to png file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5joS.png (I did not want to put the huge monstrosity into the post) and the screenshot from gsview showing the bounding box: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrJx3.png ; I also uploaded the EPS file to [rapidshare](http://rapidshare.com/files/3496701557/kruh1.eps) - I am not sure what is the preferred way for sharing files here. (The file is here just for the case that the problem description is not clear enough.)

---

I usually draw my pictures in metapost, from which I easily get EPS and PDF - which are ideal for inclusion into my TeX documents. The reason I needed conversion to some different format was that I wanted to post the picture at [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/). It is possible to upload pdf on imgur, but the result is very ugly.

---

My questions:

- Is there a way to get PNG with dimensions corresponding to bounding box?
- Any other suggestions for converting EPS to PNG using ghostscript? (Are there some more parameters I should have used?)

Comment: I don't think this is on-topic for this Q&A...

Comment: Just in case someone, who also tries to convert eps to png, stumbles upon this question; I will say that recently I have started using http://www.online-convert.com/ for this and so far I am satisfied with the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also use the `-dEPScrop` option. From the [GhostScript "How to use" page](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#EPS_parameters):

> #### EPS parameters
>
> `-dEPSCrop` Crop an EPS file to the bounding box. This is useful when converting an EPS file to a bitmap.
>
> `-dEPSFitPage` Resize an EPS file to fit the page. This is useful for enlarging an EPS file to fit the paper size when printing.
>
> `-dNOEPS` Prevent special processing of EPS files. This is useful when EPS files have incorrect Document Structuring Convention comments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. (I should have noticed this. I somehow concentrated only on occurrences of the word "png" in that document.)

Answer (score 2):

try adding `-dEPSCrop` to `gs`

OR

Why don't you try convert from Imagemagick? You're likely to find that standard on most Linux platforms.  I believe there are geometry options to the conversions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I work on Windows, so I would have to install Imagemagick. (But I probably should, it seems to be useful program.) But since I found out gs is capable of doing this, I wanted to try this possibility, too.

Comment: Then use the cygwin Imagemagick setup, it's easier to manage and setup.